# Enforce linking with a shared library with -Wl,--as-needed (when only templates are provided)

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries

I am creating a template-only C++ library. However, I'd like to provide an 'empty' shared library as well, so that through controlling SONAME I would be able to enforce rebuilds of the template consumers whenever the templates change in a way resulting in instantiated template ABI incompatibility.

Sadly, if a particular user has `-Wl,--as-needed` in his `LDFLAGS`, the linker is going to remove my shared library from `NEEDED` because the compiled executable is not requesting any symbols from it. How can I ensure that the program will *always* be linked against my library, preferably not introducing unnecessary dummy function calls (or if I have to, making them least burdening)?

*Edit*: as a note, the particular template class provides static methods, and usually only those static methods are used. Thus, it is not a good idea to rely on anything put in the constructor, and I'd really like to avoid burdening all the methods with some kind of enforcement.

---

Inspired by *@EmployedRussian*, I achieved:

```
extern int dummy;

namespace
{
    struct G
    {
        inline G()
        {
            dummy = 0;
        }
    };

    static const G g;
}
```

But sadly, that performs the assignment once for every unit including the header file.

Comment: Can't `-u` [linker option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) help? There is no dummy call needed to be made from the source. Symbol passed after `-u` will be treated as undefined and required library will be linked

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I presume I was supposed to add `-Wl,-u,some_symbol_in_the_library`, correct?

Comment: Hmm I think it is just `-u some_symbol_in_the_library` without `-Wl` option. Let me check once

Comment: I am sorry, but for some reason I am not able to get this to work with a sample program! Although it is mentioned even in the man pages that `-u symbol` should force linkage & I distinctly remember at least in one case where I had used it. Hopefully someone can point in the right direction

Comment: Well, maybe the description is from before `--as-needed` was added.

Comment: Interestingly in `ld`'s man page I can see the mention of both the options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I'd like to provide an 'empty' shared library as well, so that through controlling SONAME I would be able to enforce rebuilds of the template consumers whenever the templates change in a way resulting in instantiated template ABI incompatibility.

This will force an error at runtime.

You can trivially achieve the same result (runtime error) without using `SONAME`. In one of your template headers, put in a global object that will at runime

1. Take address of or call `libmysolib_version_<N>`, or
2. Do `dlopen(libmysolib.so, ...)` and `dlsym("libmysolib_version_<N>", ...)`

Then just keep incrementing `N` every time you break the ABI.

> preferably not introducing unnecessary dummy function calls

Taking address of `libmysolib_version_<N>` does not call a function; it just forces the runtime linker to find that symbol once (at startup). You may though run afoul of the linker garbage collection.

Comment: I'll have to think it about it a little more but thanks for the tip, it really helped me boil this down to two possible solutions.

Comment: I'm just thinking… isn't it possible that the compiler will optimize out the object seeing that the obtained pointer is not used anywhere?

Comment: Ok, I've just did more tests and clang with high enough optimization simply optimizes the whole block away.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend an alternative approach:

```
myheader.h 

namespace mylib_1 {
   void foo(); 
   //all the code goes there
}
namespace mylib = mylib_1;
```

User calls:

```
mylib::foo()
```

The code that uses different myheader version would not link as it would change the signature of the functions.

This approach is used by ICU

Comment: That is an interesting approach indeed… but what about inlined functions?

Comment: Hmm, that's not *exactly* what I was looking for. That's a nice form of renaming, true, and it should solve potential ABI clashes well. Still, it wouldn't allow forcing rebuilds of all packages using the template (i.e. if the implementation was buggy) unless I'm missing something.

Comment: If your library is header only... ALL functions are inlined. About forcing rebuild. What would force user to make a rebuild? He can install both old and new version of same SO as they have different sonames.

Comment: I mean it is very good technique, especially it prevents the situation where one part of the code compiled with different version, so if you rebuild some part, the program would not link without all the code being rebuild (of course under assumption that the different parts use your library in the interface between them)

Comment: I agree it's good to keep things running without breakage. But *we have* solutions to rebuild packages when SONAMEs change (in the package manager).